# event getx, based on screen size?

Tags: events, touch, size, screen

If i use the event.getx and y on touchlistener, how can i do to know if it's between 1/3 and 2/3 of the screen width?

public final float getX ()

Added in API level 1
getX(int) for the first pointer index (may be an arbitrary pointer identifier).

I dont know if the return coordinate is based on screen density, or screen pixels or whatever.. Does any1 have any idea how can i get screensize of my device then compare if the return coordinates are, for example, (between some margins) in the middle of the screen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

combine getX with getWidth, then getX/getwidth and you'll get the relative position